# Writing Script for Finding and Replacing Strings in Solution for Windows

Tags: c#, winforms, replace

So I want to write a script that changes the controls I have defined in my solution (c# codebase) to my own custom controls. There are two main replacements I need to make:

1) Designer.cs files 
replace `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` with `UI.CustomControls.CustomTextBox`
replace `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox` with `UI.CustomControls.ComboBox`
etc.

2) .cs files
replace TextBox with CustomTextBox 
replace ComboBox with CustomComboBox
etc.

I also will need to add references to the new custom control project. I could do this manually though. 
Any ideas for the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just use a global find and replace in visual studio ? No need to write code....

Comment: Do you want to replace all controls to your custom ones? Only some?

Comment: What do you mean by script here?? Do you want to replace your contorls at runtime using c# code?? And do you also want to add reference at runtime???

Comment: No I don't want to do any of this at runtime. I'm simply explaining that my codebase is written in c# if that make any difference. And yes I want to replace all of my controls.

Answer (score 1):

**As I get the question you don't have to write a script!**

1. Open your solution
2. Press Ctrl+H
3. Set the scoop to Current Solution
4. In the first textbox type: System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
5. In the second textbox type: UI.CustomControls.CustomTextBox
6. Toggle the Match Case button
7. Hit Enter :)

That's it, it's simple yet effective tool!